# Set focus in android

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext

My application contain one EditText, Button and some information on activity.

When it loads user always got focused on EditText, which caused softkwyboard loaded on screen. I need to set no focus on load. how to set unfocus my EditText field by default onload. So that I want to stop loading keyboard on load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the blow code in the code file then you got solution of your problem.

this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);

Answer (score 2):

Set following in the activity tag under manifest file:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden"
```